# Cocoa webkit: how to get file upload / file system access in webkit

Tags: cocoa, file-upload, webkit

I created a custom browser from the WebKit framework. I almost got everything setup.

However, when visiting a webpage with file upload (say flickr), nothing happens when I press the "Upload" button. Normally this would give an popup in safari/firefox/..

What do I need to get file upload to work with WebKit in Cocoa? NSFileHandler, NSFileManager? And how do I do it?

Regards,
Friesgaard

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Alright, I figured I out for my self.

Implement the following method in a class. Set the class as as `UIDelegate` for the `WebView` in Interface Builder.

(How to use a `NSOpenPanel` I found here:
http://ekle.us/index.php/2006/12/displaying_a_file_open_dialog_in_cocoa_w
)

```
- (void)webView:(WebView *)sender runOpenPanelForFileButtonWithResultListener:(id < WebOpenPanelResultListener >)resultListener
{       
    // Create the File Open Dialog class.
    NSOpenPanel* openDlg = [NSOpenPanel openPanel];

    // Enable the selection of files in the dialog.
    [openDlg setCanChooseFiles:YES];

    // Enable the selection of directories in the dialog.
    [openDlg setCanChooseDirectories:NO];

    // Display the dialog.  If the OK button was pressed,
    // process the files.
    if ( [openDlg runModalForDirectory:nil file:nil] == NSOKButton )
    {
        // Get an array containing the full filenames of all
        // files and directories selected.
        NSArray* files = [openDlg filenames];

        // Loop through all the files and process them.
        //for(int i = 0; i < [files count]; i++ )
        {
            NSString* fileName = [files objectAtIndex:0]; //i]; 
            // Do something with the filename.
            [resultListener chooseFilename:fileName]; 
        }
    }

}
```

ps. use `[resultListener chooseFilenames:...]` for multiple files

Comment: I use this, I can select the file but then ? When I click on the upload button in the webview it just say error. 
Do I need to handle to file upload mechanism ?

Comment: It should be handled by the UIDelegate, maybe you also have to set the WebView delegate to point at the same class? What error do you get, any error code?

Comment: I just checkedd my code. And the only thing I do is `[webView setUIDelegate:webFileUploader]` where webFileUploader contains the code above.

Comment: runOpenPanelForFileButtonWithResultListener this methode not called when i click input file button . i have connected uidelegate in interface builder itself

Comment: create a new question with your code, then it will be much easier to spot any errors

Answer (score 3):

I got it working by altering this a bit as form part is depreciated:

```
- (void)webView:(WebView *)sender runOpenPanelForFileButtonWithResultListener:(id < WebOpenPanelResultListener >)resultListener
{       
    // Create the File Open Dialog class.
    NSOpenPanel* openDlg = [NSOpenPanel openPanel];

    // Enable the selection of files in the dialog.
    [openDlg setCanChooseFiles:YES];

    // Enable the selection of directories in the dialog.
    [openDlg setCanChooseDirectories:NO];

    if ( [openDlg runModal] == NSOKButton )
    {
        NSArray* URLs = [openDlg URLs];
        NSMutableArray *files = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        for (int i = 0; i <[URLs count]; i++) {
            NSString *filename = [[URLs objectAtIndex:i]relativePath];
            [files addObject:filename];
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < [files count]; i++ )
        {
            NSString* fileName = [files objectAtIndex:i];
            [resultListener chooseFilename:fileName]; 
        }
        [files release];
    }

}
```

Comment: runOpenPanelForFileButtonWithResultListener this methode not called when i click input file button . i have connected uidelegate in interface builder itself